# custom form in admin grid not showing data in magento2

Tags: magento2

hello everyone I want to show product name in the custom form in admin grid after adding this code form is not displaying 
info.php

```
 $fieldset->addField(
        'entity_id',
        'text',
        [
            'name'        => 'entity_id',
            'label'    => __('product name'),
            'values' => $objectManager->get('\Magneto\BookFreeLayout\Model\Source\Products')->toOptionArray()

        ]
    );
```

Products.php

```
<?php

  namespace Magneto\BookFreelayout\Model\Source;

  use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource;
  use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\SourceInterface;
  use Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface;
  use Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface;

   /**
   * Item status functionality model
   */
  class Products implements ArrayInterface
 {
protected $_customerFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\CollectionFactory $customerFactory
) {
    $this->_customerFactory = $customerFactory;
}

/**
 * Get customer collection
 */
public function getCustomerCollection()
{
    return $this->_customerFactory->create();
}


/*
*   Option getter
*   @return array
*/
public function toOptionArray()
{
    $arr = $this->toArray();
    $ret = [];
    $ret[] = ['value' => 0, 'label' => 'All Customers'];
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {

        $ret[] = [
            'value' => $key,
            'label' => $value
        ];
    }

    return $ret;
}

/*
*   Get options in "key-value" format
*   @return array
*/
public function toArray()
{
    $customers = $this->getCustomerCollection();

    $customersList = array();
    foreach ($customers as $customer) {

        $customersList[$customer->getEntity_Id()] = __($customer->getName());
    }
    return $customersList;
}
 }
```

after removing values line from fieldset  rest data is coming product name is not coming

Comment: Try this, In your info.php write 'values' => \Magneto\BookFreeLayout\Model\Source\Products::toOptionArray()

Comment: no changes in the output

Comment: Remove code from toOptionArray() and try following code $data_array=array(); 
        $data_array[1]='Enable';
        $data_array[2]='Disable';
        return($data_array); If it works then there is issue with your function